# Glue + Good console not working [Hapi.js]

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi-good

Here is my config.json code:

```
{
    "connections": [
        {
            "port": 3000
        }
    ],
    "registrations": [
        {
            "plugin": "./plugins/db"
        },
        {
            "plugin": "good",
            "options": {
                "reporters": {
                    "console": [
                        {
                            "module": "good-squeeze",
                            "name": "Squeeze",
                            "args": [
                                {
                                    "log": "*",
                                    "response": "*"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "module": "good-console"
                        },
                        "stdout"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "plugin": "./routes/bookmarks"
        },
        {
            "plugin": "blipp"
        }
    ]
}
```

And server.js:

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Glue = require('glue');

const manifest = require('./config.json');

const options = {
    relativeTo: __dirname
}

Glue.compose(manifest, options, (err, server) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    server.start((err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }

        console.log(`Server is running at ${server.info.uri}`)
    });
})
```

The error I get:

> /home/master/Documents/Hapi/starter/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:736
>       throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
>       ^
>
> Error: Invalid register options {   "reporters" [1]: {
>       "console": [
>         {
>           "module": "good-squeeze",
>           "name": "Squeeze",
>           "args": [
>             {
>               "log": "*",

Any solution for this?

Comment: Time to a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

To register [the solution given here](https://github.com/hapijs/glue/issues/99#issuecomment-321672548):

```json
{
  "plugin": {
    "register": "good",
    "options": {
      "reporters": {
        "console": [
          {
            "module": "good-squeeze",
            "name": "Squeeze",
            "args": [
              {
                "log": "*",
                "response": "*"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "module": "good-console"
          },
          "stdout"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```